# why non-thread program executing faster than threading program to download datasets in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

i want to download the datasets of indian stock market companies, so i write the following code to download it, but it was taking too much of time, because, number of companies that i wanted to download are around 1700.

first i write it in regular way without using threading as shown below,

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
import time
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from threading import Thread

start = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
end = yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

t1 = time.perf_counter()


df = web.DataReader("RELIANCE.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("TCS.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("HINDUNILVR.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("HDFCBANK.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("HDFC.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("INFY.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("KOTAKBANK.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("BHARTIARTL.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("ITC.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("ICICIBANK.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("SBIN.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("ASIANPAINT.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("DMART.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("BAJFINANCE.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("MARUTI.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("HCLTECH.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("LT.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("WIPRO.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("AXISBANK.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader( "ULTRACEMCO.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("HDFCLIFE.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("COALINDIA.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("ONGC.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("SUNPHARMA.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)
df = web.DataReader("NTPC.NS", 'yahoo', start,end)


t2 = time.perf_counter()
```

print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

And **Output**,

```
Finished in 27.4473087 seconds
```

Then i saw some videos on youtube about threading, and i converted the same program as below,

```
import pandas_datareader as web
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests
import time
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
from threading import Thread

start = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
end = yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

t1 = time.perf_counter()


shareSymbols = [
   "RELIANCE.NS", "TCS.NS", "HINDUNILVR.NS", "HDFCBANK.NS", "HDFC.NS", "INFY.NS","KOTAKBANK.NS","BHARTIARTL.NS", "ITC.NS", "ICICIBANK.NS", "SBIN.NS", "ASIANPAINT.NS","DMART.NS", "BAJFINANCE.NS", "MARUTI.NS", "HCLTECH.NS","LT.NS", "WIPRO.NS", "AXISBANK.NS", "ULTRACEMCO.NS", "HDFCLIFE.NS" ,"COALINDIA.NS", "ONGC.NS", "SUNPHARMA.NS", "NTPC.NS"
]
def download_data(shareSymbol):
    df = web.DataReader(shareSymbols, 'yahoo', start,end)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(download_data, shareSymbols)    

    t2 = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
```

and **output** of above code,

```
Finished in 83.4883162 seconds
```

why first program is taking less time compare to second program? do i need to make any changes?

Comment: There’s something wrong with the second snippet. Are you missing the threaded code?

Comment: ohh sorry, now check it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python there is something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock. You might want to consider Multiprocessing for this task instead.

The concurrent.futures package has

`class concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=None, mp_context=None, initializer=None, initargs=())` for this.